How do I send data from my web server to my machine securely
I am working on a project where I have a website that is being hosted on a web server and I am making some APIs there which involves sending data from the web server to my machine.
For example I have a text box and a submit button and when I press submit it should send a https Post request to the flask application on my computer that should print out the text from the textbox.
The question is:
How do I securely send this https Post request to my machine without opening any ports and without having to create any new firewalls rules and if this is even possible.
I have made some research on ssh tunnelling but I havent quite figured out how it works and maybe there is a better solution than that so I am asking the community for help.
I havent actually tried anything yet I just made my reserach and thought it couldnt hurt to ask on stackoverflow.

Why not encrypt it?

@Masd https is already encrypted

Right, so is the problem that you don't want it to go directly to your pc?

@Masd I want a direct connection my pc but I dont want to open ports and make firewall rules so other people (maybe its better if I say hackers) can access my pc through these open ports and disabled firewall rules

The questions is: how do you leave an apartment if you can't open anything: no doors, no windows, nothing.. Quantum tunnel through??

@Masd can you explain what you mean with quantum I am not that advanced yet

quantum tunneling is a phenomenon in quantum mechanics, where a particle(s) can penetrate a barrier say for example you slam your hand against your desk, and it clips through it

Oh yeah I heard this, but I thought you could do something similiar using ssh tunneling but I dont know much about it

What I mean to say is quantum tunneling has such a low probability, that it is probably more likely for your computer to get struck by a cosmic ray, that flips some bits and you download your info that way

Your questions is analogous to how will you see the sun without eyes?

@Masd that is why I am asking here, I dont know much, I am still learning. how can I establish a connection from my computer to my web server without anyone else also being able to connect to my computer

as I am sure you understand you have some open ports right now as well, so tell me what is the difference between them hacking that port than this one?

yes of course I have ports open, but is there a difference between those ports and if I open a port on my router? because I heard its always a bad habit to open new ports on your router so what should I do then

probably the most you can do is firewall rules, and turning off the port off and on. If some hackers will need to hack you they will... If they are determined enough and profficient

@Masd so what does ssh tunneling do then?

In my opinion a large network of proxies would do the job perfectly@dani

@Masd what I know about proxies is its like a middleman for all my requests, if that is the case do I have to pay anything extra and is it complicated setting up these proxies?

tons of free proxies

@Masd what about ssh tunnelling is that a good idea?

yes i think it would

@Masd I am much rather looking forward to set up an ssh tunnel, what exactly will or does it do? Because if my web server is a house and my machine is a house, and I have a direct tunnel from my house to my web server house then noone can get into my house through the tunnel if that makes sense

it is not a physical tunnel, but actually a physical wire, would be safest thing

Have you considered to use an encrypted web push message? Just reuse existing technologies then you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Webserver to client communication without trigger by the client already exists.

setting a firewall rule to allow access to that port on your machine only from your web server is an obvious approach to use. if you don't trust your firewall to correctly implement the rules you specify, you have bigger problems.

if, as your comment implies ("my web server is a house and my machine is a house"), both machines are in your house, why does any traffic need to leave your home network for them to communicate?

@jhnc, thanks for your reply. if its possible to allow connnections from a port only from my web server then its a great solution. But do I have to open ports on my home network or can I even use already open ports? What does ssh tunnelling do, from what I knowit allows you to "smuggle" data through a port and then forward it to other ports and bypass the firewall this way, from what I know. I host on pythonanywhere and how come that my web server is in the same house as in mine if you imagine it this way.
